# Why is header content rendered twice in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a pretty basic ASP.NET MVC website and I cannot work out why my header content is getting rendered twice.

```
<!-- ViewStart -->
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!-- _Layout.cshtml -->
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
<body>

<!-- _Header.cshtml -->
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h1> Header Content</h1>

<!-- View-->
<h2>
    <div class="well">
        Body Content
    </div>
</h2>
```

What I end up with is the header content rendered twice; once in above the view and once in the view.

[image]

Rendered Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.apiUrl = '';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container body-content">
            <h1> Header Content</h1>        
            <div class="document-root" ng-app="AppHome">

                <div ng-view></div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="/Scripts/Vendor/Bootstrap/bootstrap-without-jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why!?

Note 1: On navigation to view, what I am expecting is:

- viewstart calls layout page
- Layout page adds header layout page
- Layout page inserts view into body

Note 2: As you can see from the source, this is an Angular App. I've replace the view that would be rendered with the content as shown above - this results in the picture above. But the rendered source does not include the second H1 so this would imply that the second H1 is somehow coming from the angular injected view

Note 3: In the real issue I am trying to display a menu and that gets displayed twice. As a sanity check I stripped everything down to the bare minimum as shown above; and still no dice.

Comment: it is because u r using <h1> Header Content</h1> and also  @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml") which will render Header Content as html

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't wrap `<div class="well">` in `<h2>`. `<h2>` cannot contain block-level children like `<div>`.

Comment: Does your `_ViewStart.cshtml` contain `@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_LogOnPartial.cshtml")` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your _Layout.cshtml add

> @{
>       Layout = null;
>   }

Maybe your Viewstart Page has layout mentioned which is applied to every page.

Note: Also the Views that are being included in the page must have Layout as null else will show with the layout as it is mentioned in Viewstart

Comment: Have you tried adding the above code in _Layout.cshtml. Maybe Viewstart is adding _Layout.cshtml as layout for _Layout.cshtml and hence the double header.

Comment: And can you please also share the "View Source" (Rendered HTML) for your page displayed. Will help in diagnosing.

Comment: Thanks, pointed in me in the right direction. The extra H1 is somehow getting injected by the angular view I am inserting at this point. This view ONLY contains the content as described at start of post and results in view as shown in pic.

Comment: The view you are trying to insert should have @{ Layout = null; } else _Layout.cshtml will be added by ViewStart.

Answer (score 0):

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv2Yx/)

it appears that you render `<h1> Header Content</h1>` two time.
`@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml")` this might have `<h1> Header Content</h1>` code too.

As example

```
<!-- _Layout.cshtml -->
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <h1> Header Content</h1>      
    </div>
<body>

<!-- _Header.cshtml -->
<h1> Header Content</h1>

<!-- View-->
<h2>
    <div class="well">
        Body Content
    </div>
</h2>
```

Comment: what about @RenderBody()? did you check whether this contain <h1>?

Comment: It only contains the content listed as being in the view. I.e. the H2 and the well.